# Data arrangement in vector

Tags: matlab, vector

I have the following vector:

[image]

Here is the code to produce this vector:

```
A = [11 115 167 44 51 5 6];
B = [100 1 1 87];
C = [2000 625];
D = [81 623 45 48 6 14 429 456 94];
E = [89];
F = [44 846 998 2035 498 4 68 4 1 89];

G = {A,B,C,D,E,F};

[max_val, idx] = max(cellfun(@numel, G)); % Find max sizes of vectors

% Create vector with zeros filling open matrix space
LeftIndented = zeros(idx,max_val);
for k = 1:numel(G), LeftIndented(k,1:numel(G{k})) = G{k}; end
```

I would like to have a vector with:

1. Data to the right (zeros to the left)

[image]

2. Centered data (surrounded with zeros)

[image]

(Notice that if data cannot be exactly centered, it is ok if it is off by one vector space to the left)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pad each vector with zeros:

```
A = [11 115 167 44 51 5 6];
B = [100 1 1 87];
C = [2000 625];
D = [81 623 45 48 6 14 429 456 94];
E = [89];
F = [44 846 998 2035 498 4 68 4 1 89];

G = {A,B,C,D,E,F};

[max_val, idx] = max(cellfun(@numel, G)); % Find max sizes of vectors

% Create vector with zeros filling open matrix space
LeftIndented = zeros(idx,max_val);
Centered = zeros(idx,max_val);
RightAligned = zeros(idx,max_val);
for k = 1:numel(G)
    LeftIndented(k,1:numel(G{k})) = G{k};
    l = length(G{k});
    padding = max_val - l;
    leftPadding = floor(padding / 2);
    Centered(k, :) = [zeros(1, leftPadding), G{k}, zeros(1, padding - leftPadding)];
    RightAligned(k, :) = [zeros(1, padding), G{k}];
end
```

This is equivalent to

```
A = [11 115 167 44 51 5 6];
B = [100 1 1 87];
C = [2000 625];
D = [81 623 45 48 6 14 429 456 94];
E = [89];
F = [44 846 998 2035 498 4 68 4 1 89];

G = {A,B,C,D,E,F};

[max_val, idx] = max(cellfun(@numel, G)); % Find max sizes of vectors

% Create vector with zeros filling open matrix space
LeftIndented = zeros(idx,max_val);
Centered = zeros(idx,max_val);
RightAligned = zeros(idx,max_val);
for k = 1:numel(G)
    LeftIndented(k,1:numel(G{k})) = G{k};
    l = length(G{k});
    padding = max_val - l;
    leftPadding = floor(padding / 2);
    Centered(k, 1 + leftPadding:leftPadding + l) = G{k};
    RightAligned(k, 1 + padding:end) = G{k};
end
```

but in the second code the values of the vectors are written into the correct position in a zero vector.

Comment: Great answer, but you missed the right alignment

Comment: @Irreducible Yes, I missed that part in the question. I added it now.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using [`strjust`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjust.html):

```
A = [11 115 167 44 51 5 6];
B = [100 1 1 87];
C = [2000 625];
D = [81 623 45 48 6 14 429 456 94];
E = [89];
F = [44 846 998 2035 498 4 68 4 1 89];

G = {A,B,C,D,E,F};

data = [G{:}];
N = cellfun(@numel, G);
M = max(N);
idx = char((N.' >= (1:M))+32); 

Le = strjust(idx, 'left');
Ri = strjust(idx, 'right');
Ce = strjust(idx, 'center');

LeftAdjusted = zeros(M, N);
RightAdjusted = zeros(M, N);
Centered = zeros(M, N);

LeftAdjusted(Le.' ~= ' ') = data;
RightAdjusted(Ri.' ~= ' ') = data;
Centered(Ce.' ~= ' ') = data;

LeftAdjusted = LeftAdjusted.';
RightAdjusted = RightAdjusted.';
Centered = Centered.';
```